# Store image from Android application to a MongoDB instance on server side

Tags: java, android, mongodb, httpresponse

I need to store an image from an android app to a mongodb instance on server side. Over here, my Android application is going to be the client and the server has a mongodb instance. Later on, i need to send request to the server to retrieve the images back from mongodb instance. 
Could some please provide me guidelines?

Comment: You're going to need to clarify a few things before anyone can help you. You've got "httpresponse" in your tags, does this mean you're asking how to save documents to MongoDB on the server side? Or are you asking for how to structure your client so that it sends requests to a server? Further, what do you mean by "save a clicked image?" Do you mean save to the client? Record that an image was clicked on the server? Or upload the image from the client to the server?

Comment: Thanks Knetic! i changed the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see GridFS thats part of MongoDB     http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/